# How to access dimensions and measures from qHyperCube?

Tags: qliksense

I'm very new to developing Qlik Sense extensions.

This question may sound very silly, but can anyone please tell me how to access the result matrix that contains the measures entered from the properties panel? I'm able to get the measures (`qNum` and `qText`) from `qGrandTotalRow`, but `qDataPages` is always empty.

Has it got anything to do with `initialProperties`? Currently I've left it empty.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, make sure that you have the `initialProperties` set properly, e.g:

```
initialProperties: {
    qHyperCubeDef: {
        qDimensions: [],
        qMeasures: [],
        qInitialDataFetch: [
            {
                qWidth: 10,
                qHeight: 100
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

See here for a more detailed explanation: http://qliksite.io/tutorials/qliksense-visualization-extensions/part-01/08-Hello-Data/#

Comment: Thanks! Fixed this that day itself once I went through your tutorials :)